# Python - Work with everything in the list one by one

Tags: python, list

I have a list `my_list = []`
In this list are some int's so `my_list = [1,2,3,4]`
Now I want to work with every number one by one, without knowing there are only 4 int's. There could be 1000 things in the list. I thought about sth like:

```py
i = len(self.my_list)
while i > 0:

    print(my_list[i])

    i -=1
```

but I got this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You are looking for a `for` loop.

Comment: Specifically you are getting an index error because the highest valid index for a list with len x is x - 1.

Comment: Please work through a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is iterate over each item in the list:

```
for i in my_list:
   print(i,i**2)
```

Comment: Got this Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Try to figure out the error yourself. `2` is obviously an integer, so the other value must be the string. The other value is `i`. What it is `i`? `i` is one of the values in the list `my_list`. Conclusion: check the content of your list. I'm sure you'll find at least one string in there.

Answer (score 0):

I usually using this method:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
i=0
while(i < len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
    i+=1
```

with while you have control of index.

Comment: This looks like C or Java code written in Python. Try to think pythonic. A list is iterable, so `for value in my_list:` is the way to go.

Comment: as I mentioned with this you have control of your index
sometimes i use like this
   my_list = [1,2,3,4]
   i=0
   while(i < len(my_list)):
       print(my_list[i])
       if(my_list[i] == 2):
           print(my_list[i-1])
       i+=1

Comment: You can be pythonic and have control of index: try `for (i, x) in enumerate(my_list): ...` :)